PowerShell adding section in setting json file
I have empty settings.json file
{ 
}

I want to add section with powershell and to look like this:
{
    "ParentObj":  {
                  "ChildProp":  "test"
                  }
}

I use this sample of code to achieve this :
$SettingFile = Get-Content 'c:\z\setting.json' -raw -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json 

if (-not $SettingFile.PSObject.Properties['ParentObj']) {
    $SettingFile | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ParentObj -Value @{}
}

if (-not $SettingFile.ParentObj.PSObject.Properties['ChildProp']) {
    Write-Host 'section 1'
    $SettingFile.ParentObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ChildProp' -Value 'test'
} else {
     Write-Host 'section 2'
    $SettingFile.ParentObj.ChildProp = 'test2'
}

$SettingFile | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | set-content 'c:\z\setting.json' -Encoding UTF8

On the first run of the script I always have empty ParentObj without ChildProp although it says it enter in section 1 of if to create  child prop

{
    "ParentObj":  {

                  }
}

i have workaround but i want to understand why on the first run ChildProp is not created, what I am misunderstanding about PowerShell behaviour ?

Your issue is when you do -Value @{} instead of -Value ([psobject]::new()), in simple terms:
$hash = @{}
$hash | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ChildProp' -Value 'test'
$hash                # is still an empty hash but has been wrapped in PSObject
$hash.ChildProp      # and a note property has been added to that wrapper
$hash.GetType()      # but is still a hashtable
ConvertTo-Json $hash # and json convert only tatgets the underlying object instead of the wrapper psobject

If you're running PowerShell 7 you might find it easier if you deserialize your Json -AsHashtable, you could approach your code like this:
$SettingFile = Get-Content 'c:\z\setting.json' -Raw -Encoding UTF8 |
    ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

if (-not $settingFile.ContainsKey('ParentObj')) {
    $settingFile['ParentObject'] = [ordered]@{}
}

$SettingFile['ParentObject']['ChildProp'] =
    -not $SettingFile['ParentObject'].Contains('ChildProp') ? 'test' : 'test2'

$SettingFile | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10


Replace:
-Value @{}
with:
-Value ([pscustomobject] @{})[1]

@{} creates an empty hashtable rather than a [pscustomobject], and you want the latter.
By using a hashtable, the subsequent Add-Member call decorated the empty hashtable stored in .ParentObject with a ChildProp ETS (Extended Type System) NoteProperty property, which was in effect ignored by ConvertTo-Json - only the empty hashtable itself was serialized and - given that serializing a hashtable to JSON means serializing its entries and there are none in your case - you ended up with an empty ParentObj property in the output JSON.[2]
By contrast, a [pscustomobject] instance - which doesn't wrap an instance of another .NET type - is entirely composed of NoteType properties that are all considered first-class property citizens and therefore all serialize to JSON.

[1] For historical reasons, [psobject] and [pscustomobject] refer to the same type, System.Management.Automation.PSObject, though only [pscustomobject] offers construction via an apparent cast from an apparent hashtable literal (@{ ... }), which is actually syntactic sugar. You can alternatively create an empty (property-less) instance with [psobject]::new() or New-Object psobject / New-Object pscustomobject.
[2] It is debatable whether a NoteProperty member attached to a hashtable as a whole should be ignored for the purposes of to-JSON serialization or not.
Objects that aren't enumerable do serialize with such properties, e.g.
[datetimeoffset]::now | Add-Member -PassThru foo bar | ConvertTo-Json,
although [string] and [datetime] instances are explicit exceptions - see GitHub issue #5797.
The logic seems to be: if the object at hand is perceived to be a container for other objects (rather than an object with its own properties), which also applies to [array]s and similar list-like types, any ETS properties attached to the object itself are ignored.
In the case of hashtables, this is somewhat at odds with the fact that they're often conceived of as single objects, interchangeably with [pscustomobject] instances.

